# Household Outgoings Calculator (OOP)

Tags: c++11

I would really appreciate feedback on my OOP Household Outgoings calculator. My objective is to develop in OOP. Have I used good OOP techniques? How can I improve on it? And anything else you might add. Thank you very much in advance for anyone who spends their time reviewing it. I've learned so much from this site and it has made me a better programmer. Please note, I've used Hungarian notation and I know its bad but I do have my reasons for using it. Also, I know everything hasn't been validated in terms of inputs but I just want a review on how well I've used OOP. Many thanks!

This is an example output of my program. Note: A fake address.

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
// Homeowner Breakdown System.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
class Person {
private:
    std::string m_sName;
    double m_dMonthlyIncome;
    
public:
    Person() :m_sName{ "" }, m_dMonthlyIncome{ 0 }{}
    Person(std::string sName, double dMonthlyIncome) :
        m_sName{ sName }, m_dMonthlyIncome{ dMonthlyIncome }
    {}
    void set_name(std::string sName) {
        m_sName = sName;
    }
    void set_monthly_income(double dMonthlyIncome) {
        m_dMonthlyIncome = dMonthlyIncome;
    }
    std::string get_name() const { return m_sName; }
    double get_monthly_salary() const { return m_dMonthlyIncome; }
};

class Outgoing {
private:
    std::string m_sName;
    double m_dCostPerMonth;
public:
    Outgoing() :m_sName{ "" }, m_dCostPerMonth{ 0 }{}
    Outgoing(std::string sName, double dCostPerMonth) :m_sName{ sName }, m_dCostPerMonth{dCostPerMonth} {}
    std::string get_outgoing_name() const { return m_sName; }
    double get_cost_per_month() const { return m_dCostPerMonth; }
};

class Household {
private:
    std::vector<Person>m_objPeople;
    std::string m_sAddress;
    int m_iNumberOfAdultsInHousehold;
    std::vector<Outgoing>objPleasureCosts;
    std::vector<Outgoing>objBills;
    
public:
    Household(std::string address) 
        :m_sAddress{ address }, m_iNumberOfAdultsInHousehold{0}    
    {}
    void set_address(std::string address) { m_sAddress = address; }

    std::string get_address()const { return m_sAddress; }
    int get_number_of_adults_in_household()const { return m_iNumberOfAdultsInHousehold; }
    
    double calculate_monthly_total_expenditure() const {
        return calculate_monthly_bill_costs() + calculate_monthly_pleasure_costs();
    }
    void add_new_monthly_bill(Outgoing &&objOutgoingBill) {
        objBills.emplace_back(objOutgoingBill);
    }
    void add_new_monthly_pleasure_cost(Outgoing &&objOutgoingPleasure) {
        objPleasureCosts.emplace_back(objOutgoingPleasure);
    }
    double calculate_yearly_expenditure() const {
        
        return (calculate_monthly_pleasure_costs() + calculate_monthly_bill_costs() * 12);
    }
    double calculate_monthly_savings() const {

        return calculate_total_income() - (calculate_monthly_bill_costs() + calculate_monthly_pleasure_costs());
    }
    double calculate_total_income() const {

        double dTotalIncome = 0;
        for (const Person& objPerson : m_objPeople) {
            dTotalIncome += objPerson.get_monthly_salary();
        }
        return dTotalIncome;
    }
    double calculate_total_monthly_outgoing_costs() const {
        return (calculate_monthly_pleasure_costs() + calculate_monthly_bill_costs()) * 12;
    }
    double calculate_yearly_bill_costs() const {
        return calculate_monthly_bill_costs() * 12;
    }
    double calculate_yearly_pleasure_costs() const {
        return calculate_monthly_pleasure_costs() * 12;
    }
    double calculate_monthly_bill_costs() const {
        double dSum = 0;
        for (const Outgoing& objOutcoming : objBills) {
            dSum += objOutcoming.get_cost_per_month();
        }
        return dSum;
    }
    double calculate_monthly_pleasure_costs() const {
        double dSum = 0;
        for (const Outgoing& objOutcoming : objPleasureCosts) {
            dSum = objOutcoming.get_cost_per_month();
        }
        return dSum;
    }
    void add_person_to_household(Person objPerson) {
        m_objPeople.emplace_back(objPerson);
        m_iNumberOfAdultsInHousehold++;      
    }
    void display_household_adults() const {
        std::cout << "Household...\n";
        std::cout << "Address: " << m_sAddress << "\n";
        std::cout << "Occupants...\n";
        for (const Person& objPerson : m_objPeople) {
            std::cout << objPerson.get_name() << "\n";           
        }
    } 
    void display_household_bills() const {
        std::cout << "Bills...\n";
        for (const Outgoing& objBill : objBills) {
            std::cout << "Name: " << objBill.get_outgoing_name() << "\n";
            std::cout << "Cost a month: " << char(156) << objBill.get_cost_per_month() << "\n";
            std::cout << objBill.get_cost_per_month() << "\n";
        }
    }
};

class HomeownerBreakdownSystem {
private:
    std::vector<Household> m_objHouseholds;
public:
    auto find_household(std::string address) {
        return std::find_if(m_objHouseholds.begin(), m_objHouseholds.end(), [&](auto& household) {return household.get_address() == address; });
    }

    void add_household_to_system(std::string address) {
        m_objHouseholds.emplace_back(address);
    }
    auto& newly_added_household() {
        return m_objHouseholds.back();
    }
};
bool confirm_continue() {
    unsigned char cOption = 0;
    do {
        std::cin >> cOption;
        cOption = tolower(cOption);
        if (cOption == 'y') {
            return true;
        }
        else if (cOption == 'n') {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Your answer wasn't decisive, enter either y or n: ";
            continue;
        }
       
    } while (true);
}
void display_outgoings_report(const Household &objHousehold) {

    objHousehold.display_household_adults();
    std::cout << "Household's Outgoing Total Cost: " << char(156) << objHousehold.calculate_monthly_total_expenditure() << "\n";
    std::cout << "  . Bills total cost: " << char(156) << objHousehold.calculate_monthly_bill_costs() << "\n";
    std::cout << "  . Pleasure total cost: " << char(156) << objHousehold.calculate_monthly_pleasure_costs() << "\n";
    objHousehold.display_household_bills();
    std::cout << "Monthly savings: " << char(156) << objHousehold.calculate_monthly_savings() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Total yearly expenditure: " << char(156) << objHousehold.calculate_yearly_expenditure() << "\n";
    std::cout << "  . Yearly Bill expenditure: " << char(156) << objHousehold.calculate_yearly_bill_costs() << "\n";
    std::cout << "  . Yearly Pleasure expenditure: " << char(156) << objHousehold.calculate_yearly_pleasure_costs() << "\n";
}
void establish_new_household(HomeownerBreakdownSystem &objSystem) {
    std::string sHousehold;
    std::cout << "Enter the address of household: ";
    std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, sHousehold);
    objSystem.add_household_to_system(sHousehold);
}
void enter_occupants_for_new_household(Household& objHousehold) {
    std::string sName;
    double dMonthlySalary = 0;
    unsigned char cOption = 0;
    do 
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter occupant's name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, sName);

        std::cout << "Enter occupant's monthly income " << char(156);
        std::cin >> dMonthlySalary;
        objHousehold.add_person_to_household(Person{ sName, dMonthlySalary });
          
        std::cout << "Do you wish to add another to " << objHousehold.get_address() << "? (y/n): ";
        if (confirm_continue()) {
            continue;
        }
        else 
        {
            return;
        }
    } while (true);
}
void enter_monthly_bills_to_pay_for_new_household(Household& objHousehold) {
    std::string sBillName;
    double dCostPerMonth = 0;
    unsigned char cOption = 0;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter bill's name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, sBillName);
        std::cout << "Enter bill's monthly cost: " << char(156);
        std::cin >> dCostPerMonth;
        objHousehold.add_new_monthly_bill(Outgoing{ sBillName, dCostPerMonth });

        std::cout << "Do you wish to add another to bill? (y/n): ";
        if (confirm_continue()) {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    } while (true);
}
void enter_monthly_pleasure_costs_for_new_household(Household& objHousehold) {
    std::string sPleasureName;
    double dCostPerMonth = 0;
    unsigned char cOption = 0;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter pleasure's name: ";
        std::cin >> sPleasureName;

        std::cout << "Enter pleasure's monthly cost: " << char(156);
        std::cin >> dCostPerMonth;
        objHousehold.add_new_monthly_pleasure_cost(Outgoing{sPleasureName, dCostPerMonth});
        std::cout << "Do you wish to add another pleasure cost? (y/n): ";
        if (confirm_continue()) {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    } while (true);
}

int main()
{
    HomeownerBreakdownSystem objSystem;
    establish_new_household(objSystem);
    enter_occupants_for_new_household(objSystem.newly_added_household());
    enter_monthly_bills_to_pay_for_new_household(objSystem.newly_added_household());
    enter_monthly_pleasure_costs_for_new_household(objSystem.newly_added_household());
    display_outgoings_report(objSystem.newly_added_household());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Use the required `#include`s

The code uses `std::find_if` which means that it should `#include <algorithm>`.  It was not difficult to infer, but it helps reviewers if the code is complete.

### Eliminate unused variables

Within `enter_occupants_for_new_household`, `enter_monthly_bills_to_pay_for_new_household`, and `enter_monthly_pleasure_costs_for_new_household` the variable `cOption` is declared and set, but it is otherwise unused.  It should be omitted from the program in all three places.

### Avoid overly long names

In writing this review, I typed `calculate_monthly_pleasure_costs` many times.  It's exhausting!  Show some mercy on other programmers and use shorter names.

### Don't write getters and setters for every class

C++ isn't Java and writing getter and setter functions for every C++ class is not good style. Instead, move setter functionality into constructors and think very carefully about whether a getter is needed at all. In this code, the `Person` class has public setters and getters for both name and monthly income.  If it's really desired that anything can independently set either data member, then it should be a `struct` instead. See [C.2](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-struct) for details.

### Use wide strings as needed

The code currently includes this peculiar line:

```
std::cout << "Enter occupant's monthly income " << char(156);
```

It's peculiar because of the `char(156)` at the end.  What you were trying to do is to print '£' but that's not the way to go about it.  Instead, write the line like this:

```
std::cout << "Enter occupant's monthly income £";
```

Note that, depending on the current [`locale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale), however, this may or may not render properly.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387054/how-can-i-use-stdimbue-to-set-the-locale-for-stdwcout) for how to set it explicitly.

### Don't include type information within variable names

When you write something like `m_dMonthlyIncome` in an apparent effort to convey this is a `double`, you actually actively harm your code.  It makes it less readable, more prone to maintenance problems and it's just generally a bad idea for a strongly typed language like C++.  See [NL.5](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl5-avoid-encoding-type-information-in-names).

### Fix the bug

There is an error in `calculate_monthly_pleasure_costs` in that it only looks at the first expenditure rather than all of them.  This is easily fixed by using the following suggestion.

### Use standard algorithms

Instead of writing a loop, I'd be inclined to use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to calculate the sum.  We could use a lambda to add things, but I think it would make some sense to create an `operator+` for the `Outgoing` class instead.  Here's one way to do that.

```
double operator+(double a, const Outgoing& bill) {
    return a + bill.get_cost_per_month();
}
```

Now we can rewrite `calculate_monthly_pleasure_costs`:

```
double calculate_monthly_pleasure_costs() const {
    return std::accumulate(objPleasureCosts.begin(), objPleasureCosts.end(), 0);
}
```

I'm a bit skeptical that we really need so many special functions, however, which leads to the next suggestion.

### Minimize the class interface

A good, usable interface is minimal but suffient.  That would suggest that many of the functions, such as `calculate_total_monthly_outgoing_costs`, `calculate_yearly_bill_costs`, `calculate_monthly_bill_costs` could easily be dropped.  Assume your users can multiply by 12 or add two numbers together.

### Separate input, output and calculation

To the degree practical it's usually good practice to separate input, output and calculation for programs like this.  By putting them in separate functions, it isolates the particular I/O for your platform (which is likely to be unique to that platform or operating system) from the logic of your program (which does not depend on the underlying OS).  Specifically, `enter_monthly_bills_to_pay_for_new_household` takes a reference to a `Household` object and returns `void`.  I'd suggest a better way to do it would be to take no parameters and return an `Outgoing` class instance.

Comment: Thanks very much for your review! Extremely instructive and have learned a great deal. I had a feeling my long variable names would be pointed out. Shall definitely make them shorter. Thanks for the overloading of the + operator suggestion! This is brilliant and will be applying it. Must have missed out the very top line when I copied and pasted this code as in my program the algorithm header is included. Thanks again!